# Call submit button function from jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want call OnClick function on page load with out user clicking. Can we do that in jQuery or javascript?

```
     <input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ButtonSection$RptControls$BtnSubmit" 
        class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" 
        id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ButtonSection_RptControls_BtnSubmit" 
        accessKey="o" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new 
        WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$PlaceHolderMain
                                $ButtonSection$RptControls$BtnSubmit", 
                                "", true, "", "", false, true))" 
        type="button" value="OK"/>
```

Comment: is this your original code or did you post the page source? Depending on the scope I prefer to get a generated ID such as,  'ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ButtonSection_RptControls_BtnSubmit' with, $('#<%=BtnSubmit.ClientId%>').trigger('click');

Comment: Ooh god... All answers are good and working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ButtonSection_RptControls_BtnSubmit").click();
});
```

This will trigger the `click` event on the element with the supplied `id`, and it will run when the document is fully loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can call trigger and pass the type of event to trigger.

```
$('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ButtonSection_RptControls_BtnSubmit').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing a `$("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ButtonSection_RptControls_BtnSubmit").trigger('click');` This would emulate a click on the button more info [here](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: Based on experience, trigger is the way to go. The other suggestion ( click() ) does not always work, especially when more complex event handling schemes are involved. Such as those applied via live() method.

Answer (score 1):

You imply in the question title that the button you want to click is a submit button. If so you would be better off calling the submit method of the form instead of the click event of the submit button.

```
document.forms["myform"].submit()
```

Comment: Perhaps, but there may be a listener on the submit button that does other things. I'm puzzled by the point of submitting a form onload before the user has a chance to do anything. The results may be unpredictable given the presence of autofill. Perhaps the OP is seeking to scrape information such as name and e-mail address without the user knowing.

Answer (score 0):

Or with javascript inside the body:

```
<body onload="javascript:document.getElementById('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ButtonSection_RptControls_BtnSubmit').click()" ></body>
```

The trick is to get the element and call the click method.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $btnSubmit = $('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ButtonSection_RptControls_BtnSubmit');

// Either method will work:

// Method 1: jQuery has a click event pre-defined
$btnSubmit.click();

// Method 2: some events (such as newly defined HTML5 events) 
// may not be pre-defined, so .trigger('[event]') is a way to 
// explicitly invoke that event
$btnSubmit.trigger('click');
```

Comment: Using jQuery to "fire" listeners that weren't added using jQuery is problematic. It has its own event registration and handling mechanism, it doesn't use the W3C [disptachEvent](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventTarget-dispatchEvent).

Comment: can you expand on specific problems?